# Android Intent Filter Hide Activities with Certain Category

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Is it possible to make an intent that shows activities that are in the apps drawer but arent homescreen apps (e.g. GoLauncher) so i.e. it hides a certain category?

```
        final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.removeCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); //Doesn't work
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        [...]
        apps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

With this code they still get listed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry, there's no "not" operator with an `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is only valid in a *literal* sense. While you cannot exclude items with `Intent.CATEGORY_HOME`, you can filter them from the results. Here is a kotlin example -

```
    val packages = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
        mainIntent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER)
    packages.removeIf { item -> null != item.filter
            && item.filter.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME) }
```